# How can I insert a field from storage into my SQL query in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have made an SQL statement like the following example:

```
SELECT ip
FROM ip_table
LIMIT 500
```

Then I saved the result into a google storage table as a csv format. Now I found that I want more data about the ips I queries previously. Can I read the ips that I saved in the previous query and use them into a new query like this:

```
SELECT mroe_info
FROM ip_table
WHERE ip = ip_from_my_csv_file
```

Where `ip_from_my_csv_file` should iterate over the `ips` I have in my csv file.

Can you help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create external table (for example named `my_csv_file`) on top of your csv file (see [`Using External Data Sources`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources)) and than use it in your query

```
SELECT mroe_info
FROM `project.dataset.ip_table`
WHERE ip in (SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM `project.dataset.my_csv_file`)
```